# iPhone 6 Plus Sounds Stopped Working

Tags: ios, notifications

I've check all my settings, my phone is not in Do Not Disturb mode, but I cannot get my alert sounds (messages, phone calls, etc) to work. Only vibrate works. Toggling settings off and on does not work either.

Comment: something stuck in the headphone socket?

Comment: I've linked to some of the many settings that need to be checked. If you want to edit to list each setting you have checked - that might help us help you. Hopefully the broad HW/SW troubleshooting in my answer will help in any event.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't play music either or listen to voicemails (to check the receiver and the speaker) then you have a hardware or software issue.

If you can play music and listen to voicemails, then you have a software issue or a [configuration/setting mismatch with what you want](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237240/iphone-not-getting-audio-alerts-from-texts-and-other-notification-events) the device to do.

Hardware issue - usually starts with eliminating software issues, but in this case observing the headphone port for damage might be a great quick fix.

Software issues, back up the device and test after restoring it and verifying the settings.